# how to install the watchdogs pip for python

Tags: python

hey i was wondering if someone could tell me how to install the watchdogs pip for python i'm using visual studio code was wondering if that made any difference i cant figure it out and nothing on youtube

```
pip install watchdog
```

tried this and many other things in python console and VSCode

```
>>> pip install watchdog
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install watchdog
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install watchdog
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install watchdog
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip3 install watchdog
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip3 install watchdog
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> py -m pip install [watchdog]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -m pip install [watchdog]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

that was in the python console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/fileSortProgram/fileSort.py", line 1, in <module>
    from watchdog.observer import observer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'
```

that was in vscode

Comment: I just want to verify if you have `python` installed? If you do then in VS Code, click on the terminal menu item on the top (it should be next to help) then click on new terminal. A terminal should open up. Run `pip install watchdog` here. Are you still getting this error?

Comment: yes still getting an erroe here is the error

Comment: PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\fileSortProgram> pip install watchdog
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install watchdog
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\fileSortProgram>

Comment: are you on python 2 or python 3? Try running `pip3 install watchdog` if you are on python 3

Comment: still not working and 3.8

Comment: is it a problem with me being in PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\fileSortProgram>

Comment: `pip` is a command line program ... not something you type into a python interpreter (which is what you are doing in **all** your examples)

Comment: I don't think you've set `pip` in your environment variables. If you set it in your environment variable the command prompt will recognize it as a command. When you add an environment variable, you're essentially creating a shortcut to the `pip.exe` file

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to install pip itself.  My computer had this problem, and I had to install pip using the shell. You can use the official tutorial here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: so that partially work pip installed successfully but where do i put python get-pip.py

Comment: I ended up putting it in venv

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you haven't set `pip` in your environment variables.
try adding `pip` to your environment variables.
Here's a good tutorial on how to do it https://appuals.com/fix-pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: still not working and i have no clue why